# Pandas how replace values of every sentences starting by specific char?

Tags: python, pandas

```
I have a daframe like this:

    Sentences
0   "a) Sentence 1"
1   "b) Sentence 2"
```

I would like to ignore "a) " and "b) " at the beginning of every row of the column Sentences.

I tried to code it: When the three first char of a sentence is 'b) ' I take the [3:] of the sentence:

```
df.loc[df.Names[0:3] == 'b) ', "Names"] = row['Names'][3:]
```

But doesn't work

Expected output:

```
    Sentences
0   "Sentence 1"
1   "Sentence 2"
```

Comment: regex replace? `df['Sentences'].str.replace('[a-z]\) ', '', regex=True)`

Answer (score 2):

Using below as sample:

```
    Sentences
0   a) Sentence 1
1   b) Sentence 2
2   This is a test sentence
3   NaN
```

You can use `pd.Series.str.startswith` to check for rows starting with a) and b), and then assign directly:

```
df.loc[df['Sentences'].str.startswith(("a) ","b) "), na=False), "Sentences"] = df['Sentences'].str[3:]

print (df)

                 Sentences
0               Sentence 1
1               Sentence 2
2  This is a test sentence
3                      NaN
```

Comment: I tried your code, thanks. I have the error: ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values. Maybe I can do .fillna('') in the column ?

Comment: You seem to have `NaN` values in your sentences column. If so add `na=False` as edited above.

Comment: Thanks, now I have 'ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis' and don't know how avoid it. Not sure if I have to do df.reset_index(inplace=True) before applying your solution

Answer (score 0):

Try the str.replace function of the column like this

df.sentence.str.replace(".) ", "")

this will return a dataframe that you want I think.

Reference str.replace():
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html?highlight=str%20replace#pandas.Series.str.replace

str.replace takes a regular expression or string and replaces it with another string. For more info please see the link above.

Comment: @MrFuppes regex is more accurate than mine I think. Do you have rows with more than one character before the ")" ?

Answer (score 0):

If every sentence is going to start with a letter followed by a ')' and assuming you don't want to replace additional occurrences of `)` after the first one, this will work

```
df["Sentences"] = df["Sentences"].str.split("\) ", expand=True).drop(0, axis=1).to_numpy().sum(axis=1)
```